# SQL Server : database log reported failure but succeded

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

I've configured logshipping for my production databases, but for one database I'm getting weird errors.

Every day I'm receiving one following message from SQL Server Agent:

```
JOB RUN: 'Backup db01 log to SRV01' was run on 2024-02-09 at 18:10:00  
DURATION: 0 hours, 0 minutes, 52 seconds
STATUS: Failed
MESSAGES: The job failed.  The Job was invoked by Schedule 44 (Every 10 min).  The last step to run was step 1 (Backup db01 log).
```

Despite this error message my backup log ends successfully and `.bak` file is created in location.

This happens only once per day.

I didn't find problem with job itself or increased traffic in database.

Comment: are you sure, error message is generated at this point in the job, in some cases if you are continuing within the exception block, job will continue and not abort the job run. you will have to raise the exception and exit the job run at that time